# loadPreviewImageWithOptions options dictionary

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing an iOS app share extension, and I wanted to obtain a large preview image. After some effort, I was able to make this code work:

```
class ShareViewController: SLComposeServiceViewController {

    // This is the result handler for the call to loadPreviewImageWithOptions        
    let imageHandler: NSItemProviderCompletionHandler = { [unowned self]
        (result: NSSecureCoding?, error: NSError!) in

        if result is UIImage
        {
            let image = result as! UIImage

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                self.imageView.image = image
                self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
                self.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
            })
        }
    }

    // Find the shared item and preview it.
    for item: AnyObject in self.extensionContext!.inputItems
    {
        let inputItem = item as! NSExtensionItem
        for provider: AnyObject in inputItem.attachments!
        {
            let provider = provider as! NSItemProvider

            // I want a preview image as large as the device.
            var options_dict = [NSObject:AnyObject]()
            options_dict[NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey] = NSValue(CGSize: CGSize(width: 960, height:540))

            provider.loadPreviewImageWithOptions(options_dict, completionHandler: imageHandler)
        }
    }

...
}
```

I obtain an image, but its size is always 84 x 79 pixels. From the [NSItemProvider documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSItemProvider_Class/) the options dictionary should support preview image size:

> *options* - A dictionary of keys and values that provide information about the item, such as the size of an image. For a list of possible keys, see Options Dictionary Key.

And under Options Dictonary Key on the same page:

> *NSItemProviderPreferredImageSizeKey* - 
>   A key specifying the dimensions of an image in pixels. The value of this key is an NSValue object containing a CGSize or NSSize data type.

There is one clue:

> Keys are used in the dictionary passed to the options parameter of a NSItemProviderLoadHandler block.

So maybe I have to call or override loadItemForTypeIdentifier with the size option, and then call loadPreviewImageWithOptions? I'm trying this now.

Comment: did you get this to work?? I'm trying to do the same!